Convert variable (i.e., string) to vector of same name
I'm really struggling with using variables.  By "variables" I mean a string that is a substitute for a value, numeric or other. Some of my research found that R calls columns variables. And rows are observations.
Anywho, I need to create a set of charts, over and over.  These charts show measurements across time for database performance.
I have all the measurements collected in individual vectors.  I have a function that creates a chart for a given vector.  I would like to use a loop to run through all of the vectors creating a chart for each.  Because each chart uses a different vector, title, x label, and is different based on whether the measurement is percentile based, I feed the four conditions into the function.
I have tried creating a separate data frame to house all four variables in each column, but when I run the loop I get an error message because the vector name isn't being seen as a vector.
Basically, I need to convert "CPU_PCT" the string to CPU_PCT the vector when I call the function.
Here is a sample of the data and what I have so far:
Sample code (where I'm at so far):
df2 <- data.frame(
      c("CPU_PCT","% CPU Utilization","Utilization",1),
      c("DATA_HIT_RATIO","Bufferpool Data Hit Ratio","Hit Ratio",1),
      c("AVG_RQST_MS","Average Response Time","Milliseconds",0),
      c("TX_PER_SEC","Total Transactions per Second","Transactions",0)
      )

# plot each metric
for (i in 1:ncol(df2)){
  source("scripts/functions/TimeSeriesChart.R")

  A <- c(df2[1,i])
  B <- c(df2[2,i])
  C <- c(df2[3,i])
  D <- as.numeric(df2[4,i])

  # set directory path and file name 
  dir <- file.path("output", "dataExports", A)
  
  # add file extension
  file <- paste(dir, "png", sep=".")  
  
  # open file for storing graph
  png(file=file, res=100, width=800, height=325)
  
  # create the graph
  print(create_TS_Chart(A,B,C,D))
  
  # close the file
  dev.off()
}

Working function (when called from outside the loop):
#========================================================== 
# Function rules:
#   - This function is fed one column only
#   - The second column is always TIMESTAMP
#   - The x axis is always the date
#   - The function is fed these variables:
#         - colName = the name of column to be plotted
#         - chartTitle = title name of chart
#         - name1 = name for legend
#         - pChk = used to set y axis limits for percentile
#           graphs (1 or 0)
#
#   USAGE: print(create_TS_Chart(DEADLOCKS_PER_HOUR,"DEADLOCKS PER HOUR","Qty",0))
#
#========================================================== 

create_TS_Chart=function(cName,chartTitle,name1,pChk){
  # ensure libraries are loaded
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggthemes)
  
  # create data frame
  df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP, cName)

  # remove rows with missing values
  df <- na.omit(df)

  # get the number of digits in the max value
  # used for rounding off the y axis limits
  num=round(log10(max(df[,2]))-1, digits=0)
  
  # prevent 'num' variable from being negative
  num <- ifelse(num<0, 0, num)

  # check if y axis limits should be based on percentages
  # if not, round up 1 std deviation and round down 1 std deviation
  yLowChoice <- ifelse(pChk==1, 0, round(floor(min(df[,2])-sd(df[,2])),digits=-num))
  yHighChoice <- ifelse(pChk==1, 100, round(ceiling(max(df[,2])+sd(df[,2])),digits=-num))
  
  # ensure that the high limit is not less than the 'yBrks' denominator
  # 5 is the break distance for the y axis because it is visually appealing
  yHighChoice <- ifelse(yHighChoice<5, 5, yHighChoice)
  
  # verify that low limit is not negative
  yLowChoice <- ifelse(yLowChoice<0, 0, yLowChoice)
  
  # set variables
  #chartTitle=""
  #name1=""
  name2="Moving Average"
  xName=""
  yName=""
  yLow=yLowChoice
  yHigh=yHighChoice
  yBrks=round(yHigh/5, digits=0)
  color1="#56B4E9"
  color2="#009E73"
  
  # set legend location accordingly (i.e., top or bottom)
  # if the mean is greater than 60% of the max value set legend at bottom
  if(mean(df[,2])>(max(df[,2])*0.6)){
    pos=c(0.15,0.17)
  } else {
    pos=c(0.15,0.9)
  }
  
  # create the chart
  ggplot(df, aes(df[,1])) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=df[,2], color=name1), linewidth=0.5) +
    geom_line(aes(y=rollmean(df[,2], k=18, fill=NA, align="right"),
                  color=name2),
              linewidth=1) +
    labs(x=xName, y=yName) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(yLow, yHigh), 
                       breaks=seq(yLow, yHigh, by=yBrks)) +
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks="1 days",date_labels="%b-%d") +
    scale_colour_manual(breaks=c(name1, name2), values=c(color1, color2)) +
    ggtitle(chartTitle) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position=pos,
          legend.text=element_text(size=12),
          legend.title=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_text(size=14),
          axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
          axis.text.y=element_text(size=12),
          plot.title.position='plot',
          plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=16))
}

Sample data:
> head(TIMESTAMP)
[1] "2024-08-06 00:15:03 CDT" "2024-08-06 00:30:02 CDT" "2024-08-06 00:45:03 CDT"
[4] "2024-08-06 01:00:02 CDT"
> head(CPU_PCT)
[1] 2.724467 2.392535 4.087336 3.750948 2.735335 3.557698
> head(AVG_RQST_MS)
[1]  6.884603  7.999380 10.264731 12.090642 10.665872  9.433936
> head(DATA_HIT_RATIO)
[1] 0.9387146 0.9731671 0.9581920 0.9472772 0.9478335 0.9884797
> head(TX_PER_SEC)
[1] 27.18354 23.73252 19.47831 19.00333 18.79889 20.38154

I have read through and tried various suggestions from these sites/pages:

Remove quotes from a character vector in R

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-character-string-to-variable-name-in-r/

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/strex/html/str_to_vec.html



An answer saw provided in staging ground: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79016915
